# What do you call a person that adds things to a list?

Tags: single-word-requests

Would "adder" be a valid term?

The person is someone who adds an item to the list.

Comment: `Adder` would not be a valid term and would probably be confusing (an adder is a type of snake, and in circuit design can mean something that sums other items).

Comment: Perhaps "inserter"? "introducer"?

Comment: This is for a label on a UI, right?

Comment: @Mitch, yes. I'm leaning towards `contributor` at the moment for the general label but for one list, its a list of peoples names so it could seem a little strange - "Contributor" and "Attendee". For all other lists it would fit more appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ***"contributor"*** can be used for someone who *contributes* to the list.

Context is a factor here, of course.  If you have a group of colleagues sitting around compiling a list of issues for their manager, each person adding an item to the list would have *contributed* to the list, thereby making them a *contributor*.

Comment: It should be spelled [*contributor.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contributor)

Answer (score 3):

If a single person is responsible with the management of a list, you could say that person is *keeping* or *managing* the list. You could go ahead and call the person a *list keeper* or *list manager*.

If multiple persons can add items to a list, then you can say those who added items *contributed* to the list. They can be considered *(list) contributors*.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate term is usually "editor":

> [editor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/editor) — a person who edits material for publication, films, etc.

An editor will be responsible for adding, removing or updating items in a list.

There is no specific term for someone who *only* adds items to a list. You would have to use a term such as "the one who adds to the list". The closest term would be "compiler":

> compiler — a person who compiles.
>
> compiles — to put together (documents, selections, or other materials) in one book or work.

You can "compile a list" and someone who does this is a "compiler of lists". But this usually refers to the person who created the entire list -- not someone who simply added a few items here and there. That would be an "editor".

Answer (score 0):

When I read the question, “enumerator” sprang to mind. 
I was somewhat disappointed to see that it was generally defined
as someone who reads from a list rather than someone who creates (or extends) a list,
but [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enumerator) defines it
as “one that [enumerates](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enumerates);
*especially* :  a census taker”.

And, if you’re willing to consider a narrative history to be a form of a list
(i.e., a list of events),
then [chronicler](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chronicler) might fit.